# Efficent way to find index of member in string enum

Tags: python, performance, enums

I have a constant Enum class that looks something like this:

```
class Animals(Enum):
    Dog= 'dog'
    Cat= 'cat'
    Chicken = 'chicken'
    Horse = 'horse'
```

I need to find a simple and efficient way to find the index of one of the members of the Enum. so I came up with the following oneliner:

```
list(Animals).index(Animals.Chicken)
```

output:

```
2
```

The problem is, parsing to a list and searching it again is not efficient enough, and I can't change the constant.
It feels like there should be a simple solution that I'm missing.

Comment: Create a dict once to map string to index. Then you can use it repeatedly and efficiently.

Comment: What's the use case? You can access an `Enum` member by its `name` or its `value`, why do you need to worry about the index?

Comment: @gimix I'm using it to send metrics about a process and the function needs to receive an integer. It's later being parsed by a different program

Answer (score 1):

Since `Enum` member names do not start with numbers, you can simply make your `Enum` subclass' `_member_map_` attribute, a dict that stores the member name-to-value mapping, to also store the index number-to-value mapping.

This can be done by subclassing `Enum`'s metaclass, `EnumMeta`, and adding indices as new keys to all corresponding values for the `_member_map_` attribute, in the class object returned by the original `__new__` method:

```
from enum import Enum, EnumMeta

class IndexableEnumType(EnumMeta):
    def __new__(metacls, cls, bases, classdict, **kwargs):
        enum_class = super().__new__(metacls, cls, bases, classdict, **kwargs)
        for i, v in enumerate(list(enum_class._member_map_.values())):
            enum_class._member_map_[i] = v
        return enum_class
```

So that:

```
class Animals(Enum, metaclass=IndexableEnumType):
    Dog= 'dog'
    Cat= 'cat'
    Chicken = 'chicken'
    Horse = 'horse'

print(Animals[2])
print(Animals['Chicken'])
print(Animals.Chicken)
```

would output:

```
Animals.Chicken
Animals.Chicken
Animals.Chicken
```

Since dict lookups costs *O(1)* in average time complexity, this is much more efficient than your current solution of calling `list.index`, which costs *O(n)* in time complexity.

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/AdventurousVapidCollaborativesoftware

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options:

- Use the index values as the values of your `Enum`, or perhaps `IntEnum`

```
class Animals(Enum):
    Dog= 0
    Cat= 1
    Chicken = 2
    Horse = 3
Animals.Chicken.value #returns 2
```

- If you want to keep the textual description too, then subclass `Enum`, and add the needed attributes (see the [Planet example](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/enum.html?highlight=enum#planet) in the docs):

```
class Animals(Enum):
    Dog = ('dog',0)
    Cat = ('cat',1)
    Chicken = ('chicken',2)
    Horse = ('horse',3)
    def __init__(self, textval, idx):
        self.textval = textval
        self.idx = idx
Animals.Chicken.value #returns ('chicken', 2)
Animals.Chicken.textval #returns 'chicken'
Animals.Chicken.idx #returns 2
```